# How can I prevent Django from "forgetting" information whenever I make a Git commit?

Tags: python, django, git, sqlite, github

I am working on a blog project in Django that I currently have a version running in production. I have been making changes to the Development version and as I push through the changes on Git I notice that every commit "clears" information I had stored in the production server. To be specific, a) certain blog posts that were written on the production server and b) user 'accounts' added on the production server seem to "disappear" whenever I push through new commits.

I was told that this problem is potentially due to my usage of sqlite (I use sqlite3) and my local dev database getting "mixed in" with my repository. If this is the case, how can I fix this problem. If you suspect this is due to a different issue, what may be the cause?

I am new to using both Django and Git though I have used Python for some time. I really appreciate any and all help. For ease of use, part of my "Articles" model is below - the articles represent blog posts.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    #Body is the "body" of our entry - self explanatory. 
    body = models.TextField()
    #date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    )
```

Comment: Are you tracking the database with Git?

Comment: Whenever I make changes that are pushed through I save them to Git, I am not sure if that is what is meant by "tracking," but if so, yes.

Comment: Changes to the database?

Comment: yes. I am tracking them on Git.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django, where is the DB located?

Comment: Within my repository on Git - within the repo I have a file 'db.sqlite3' which stores the database contents. So this file exists both in my production directory as well as on Git itself.

Comment: Okay then just have Git ignore that specific file. Since it's an sqlite DB I think that's all you need to do.

Comment: When I add *.sqlite3 to my gitignore and follow the instructions the below user advised I get a server error and can't access the page at all (Server Error 500). When I add **/db to my gitignore file, no changes at all are detectable. Is there something I'm missing with gitignore that falls in between server error and no changes? Thank you so so much for all your time and help.

Comment: Is there any more information on that error available server-side? Logs, something like that?

Comment: So, the file structure for my repo on Github is saved in a repo called "news" and it has subfolders: 1) articles, 2) pages, 3) newspaper_project...it also has files 1) .gitignore, 2) Pipfile, 3) db.sqlite3 (amongst others). Whenever I run a commit I do the following. 1) git status, 2) git add -A, 3) git commit -m "message", 4) git push -u origin master, 5) heroku git:remote -a "url", 6) git push heroku master and 7) heroku open. However once I get to step 7 many changes I've made production side have disappeared. Is this relevant and/or enough info? Sorry if its not what you meant I'm a bitnew

Answer (score 1):

add a `.gitignore` file to your repo, add the line `*.sqlite3` to it, run the following `git rm --cached *.sqlite3`

Your entire database is in the sqlite file. You have one in dev that is currently tracked by your repo. Every time you make a change in dev and commit, it overwrites your prod database with your dev database.

Answer (score 0):

Git commit cannot make things disappear nor the push command.

If I understand it right, you have your sqlite file in version control. You shouldn't do that. In that way you mess data between development and production.

Comment: Sorry for being so slow about this but how would I fix that problem? While I understand conceptually what is going on (sort of), I don't understand at all how to practically fix the issue.